# Error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION on setup and non-setup objects

Tags: apex, sobject, unit-test

In my test class i have the creation of a dummy custom setting and a dummy lead:

```
Group g1 = new Group(Name='group name', type='Queue');

            insert g1;
            QueuesObject q1 = new QueueSObject(QueueID = g1.id, SobjectType = 'Lead');

            insert q1;


    SetOwner__c mycs = SetOwner__c.getValues('standardset'); 
             if(mycs == null) {             
                 mycs = new SetOwner__c(Name= 'CustomValues');
                 mycs.OwnerId__c ='00520000000z3PrAAI';
                 mycs.RecordtypeID__c='012L00000004QsrIAE';
                 insert mycs;

    Lead lead = createNewLead(u2.id);          
                insert lead;
```

ERROR:

```
MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): SetOwner__c, original object: QueueSobject: []
```

I get this error because i am trying to perform DML on setup and non-setup objects in the same transaction.

Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can resolve this in your test class by using **System.runAs**.

```
System.runAs ( new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()) ) {
    ...your setup-object DML...
}
```

If you need to do this in a non test scenario @future, Batch Apex, apex:actionFunction or something as simple as user button flow, it can be used to separate the transactions. The Salesforce [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm) goes into the non test scenario a little further. This Database.com variant (equally applicable to Force.com) on the same help topic goes into the [testing](http://docs.database.com/dbcom/en-us/db_apex/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm?version=184.0) use case further.

Comment: Your most welcome! :-)

Comment: Hey @ca_peterson, thanks for the tweak nice optimisation! Not sure where I first heard about it tbh, though I did actually find this pattern well covered in several blogs forums and sf docs as I was checking my understanding of it.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited your answer to create the User sobject in memory instead of from the database - helps avoid an extra query.

Comment: interestingly works for permission set test Mixed DML operation issues also, thanks!

Comment: Yeah spookly, i had just used this in some code i wrote when your upvote came through! :-)

Comment: 4 years later and I just had to use this for setting test cases for a Community. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad this worked in my case.  I already had a System.RunAs() in my test class to negative test less privileged users based on Permission Set Assignments.  The good news is we can have multiple System.RunAs() with different users in the same test case (method).  So I needed to 1) give the permission set, 2) create a record as admin, then 3) as the other user try to update that record.