# System.runAs(new user(ID = UserInfo.getUnserID());

Tags: apex, unit-test

What does this mean?

```
System.runAs(new user(ID = UserInfo.getUserID());
```

Comment: It means Apex best practices should be read again and leave the coding until learned the concept. This line should run the code as logged in user but in a separate context.

Comment: @Ashwani - I have not written this. It confused me with why the new user is getting created and how can ID for new user be same as existing.

Comment: @Ashwani - In what separate context ?

Comment: It is a run time instance it won't create the user with same id. Context means, it would reset governor limits for the code written in that statement block.

Comment: @Ashwani - How will it reset the governor limit for code written in that statement block ?

Comment: @Ashwani - It does not reset governor limits, it simply changes the execution context

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [UserInfo.getUserId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm#apex_System_UserInfo_getUserId) gets the Id of the current user
- `new user(ID = UserInfo.getUserID()` will get a User record which represents the current logged in User
- [System.runAs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm) will execute any code in that code block as the user specified.

Your code effectively does nothing because the line is being terminated by a `;`. The correct syntax would be:

```
System.runAs(someUser) {
    // Execute this code as someUser
}
```

The most likely reason this is in your code is to avoid `MIXED_DML_OPERATION` errors. Have a look at [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/error-mixed-dml-operation-on-setup-and-non-setup-objects) for more information

Comment: +1.  To clarify: although the code is already being executed as the current user, `System.runAs(new user(ID = UserInfo.getUserID())) { }` does have an effect.  The code inside the block executes within a new execution context.  Hence why it's useful for avoiding `MIXED_DML_OPERATION` errors.  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/error-mixed-dml-operation-on-setup-and-non-setup-objects