# Error Message : System.DmlException when tring to insert an record in Test class

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests

My test is failing when I am trying to insert an record in test class. I am not sure why it is happening. Can someone help. The error message I get is:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): Shipping_Address__c, original object: UserRole: []

```
@istest
public class Test_SalesrepMapping{
    static testMethod void testMethod_SalesrepMapping(){
    test.startTest();  

    //Inserting an user1
    Profile pId =[Select id from Profile where name = :'System Administrator'];
    User u=new User();
    u.LastName='Test';
    u.Alias='testuser';
    u.Email='test.user@stemcell.com';
    u.Username='user.test@stemcell.com';
    u.CommunityNickname='UserA';
    //Inserting a Role 
    UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole', Name = 'My Role');
    insert r;
    u.EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1';
    u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
    u.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
    u.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
    u.ProfileId = pId.Id;
    insert u;
    System.runAs(u){
    //Inserting an user2
    Profile pId1 =[Select id from Profile where name = :'Outside Sales'];
    User u1=new User();
    u1.LastName='Test1';
    u1.Alias='tuser1';
    u1.Email='test.user1@stemcell.com';
    u1.Username='test.user1@stemcell.com';
    u1.CommunityNickname='UserB';
    //Inserting a Role 
    UserRole r1 = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'CustomRole', Name = 'Rep Role');
    insert r1;
    u1.EmailEncodingKey='ISO-8859-1';
    u1.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
    u1.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
    u1.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
    u1.ProfileId = pId.Id;
    insert u1;

    Territory__c territory = Test_CustomObjectUtil.createTerritory();


    /*Inserting a Territory 
    List<Territory__c> terrList= new List<Territory__c>{
         new Territory__c(Name = 'USABC', Fiscal_Year__c = '2017'),
         new Territory__c(Name = 'USXYZ', Fiscal_Year__c = '2017')
    };
    insert terrList; */


    //Insert a SalesRepMapping record
    Sales_Territory_Mapping__c SRM = new Sales_Territory_Mapping__c();
    SRM.Role__c='ISALM';
    SRM.Sales_Rep__c=U.id;
    SRM.SoldInTerritoryId__c=territory.id;
    insert SRM; 
    SRM.Sales_Rep__c=u1.id;
    update SRM;
    }

    //Inserting a Shipping Address (Test class in failing here)
    Shipping_Address__c ShipAd = new Shipping_Address__c();
    ShipAd.Name = 'CAWEST';
    ShipAd.Country__c='CANADA';
    ShipAd.State__c='BC';
    insert ShipAd;
    //ShipAd.City__c='Vancouver';
    //update ShipAd;

    test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Can someone tell me how to put the above code in proper format.

Comment: You can find detail [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm)

Comment: Do you need to `UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole', Name = 'My Role');`? If you remove it, it may work(I don't know if locales matter).  If you need User Roles you will need to use `System.runAs();`

Comment: You don't need `@future`. You just need to properly use `system.runAs`. See: [Error: MIXED\_DML\_OPERATION on setup and non-setup objects](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/error-mixed-dml-operation-on-setup-and-non-setup-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove..

```
 UserRole r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole', Name = 'My Role');
```

With that being said If you need User Roles you will need to use [System.runAs()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm), [this blog](http://www.tgerm.com/2012/04/mixeddmloperation-dml-operation-on.html) has some answers on how to it do.

I can't find any documentation on the functionality of this but you can insert users and it isn't "considered" a set up object, when you create a user role and insert it will cause the DML expcetion.  Some more information on Set up objects below..

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm#apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects